# Tailwind breakpoint classes are not rendering based on the breakpoint

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailwind.css. I got stuck while using the responsive css classes. I tried applying the width to an element, but the default mobile class is only getting applied, but not the breakpoint css. The class names are available in the tailwind css library.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Highlighted the issue]

Below is **tailwind.config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: [
      './src/hbs/**/*.hbs',
      './src/js/**/*.js',
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Configure your color palette here
      primary: {
          red: '#D9272E',
          orange: '#EF7622',
          teal: '#00B3C9',
          grey: '#818181',
      },
      secondary: {
          tealDark: '#0099AC',
          tealDarkest: '#007E8F',
          black: '#1A1818',
          darkGrey: '#4D4D4F',
          grey: '#DBDBDB',
          lightGrey: '#F7F7F7',
          white: '#FFFFFF',

      }
    },
    fontFamily: {
      "exo": ['"Exo"'],
    },
    screens: {
      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
    },
    fontSize: {
  //     // mobile
      // cfs: customFontSize
      'cfs': '1rem',
      'c2fs': '1.125rem',
      'c3fs': '1.188rem',
      'c4fs': '1.25rem',
      'c5fs': '1.313rem',
      'c6fs': '1.5rem',
      'c7fs': '2rem',
      'c8fs': '2.375rem',
      'c9fs': '2.75rem',
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your `tailwind.config.js` file and where the HTML is coming from? It may also be helpful if you could share a repository or CodeSandbox replicating your issue.

Comment: @person_v1.32 updated the tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 0):

This snippet:

```
plugins:[
  require('postcss-import'),
  require('tailwindcss'),
  require('autoprefixer'),
],
```

Belongs in your `postcss.config.js` not your `tailwind.config.js`. Here is the relevant documentation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports.

Edit:
The rest of your config works fine, here it is working on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GfSHtFeX7d?file=config).

Comment: I have a purge plugin in webpack, commenting out that worked, but It generates all wanted styles in the prod bundle.